# How can the gap in Opal Koboi's timeline be explained?

Tags: artemis-fowl

I just reread the Artemis Fowl series for the first time in AGES, and I just remembered this glaring plot-hole: the past-Koboi was brought into the future, and left to die. If we were to follow the timeline of the present Koboi, all the way back to before the Haven Goblin Rebellion, how could one explain the missing link between the time that the past-Koboi stepped into the future, and the Rebellion?

(I understand perfectly that everything Koboi did was undone when her past self was murdered, but there has to be a plausible reason why ONE incarnation of her was alive to set it up and carry it out in the first place.)

Comment: It's pretty similar to the time theory in *Avengers: Endgame*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

I might be wrong here, Time travel is not my specialty!  **[The Multiverse theory](http://www.quora.com/Time-Travel/What-will-happen-if-you-kill-your-past-self)** (**Please read the link on The Multiverse theory. It exactly answers the question you have raised.**) could explain your question.

Based on this text, it looks like present (elder) Opal's time line did not change.

> “Opportunity had presented itself to Opal when her younger self had made telepathic contact.
>
> One morning Opal had been deep in a cleansing coma and—ping!—suddenly there was a voice in her head, calling her Sister and asking for help. It had occurred to her briefly that she could in fact be insane but, little by little, the information filtered through. A younger Opal had followed Artemis Fowl from the past.
>
> I have no memory of this, Opal realized. Therefore, my younger self must have been captured and sent back with these events wiped from her mind.”

Excerpt From: Eoin Colfer. “Artemis Fowl 08 - The Last Guardian.”

The younger Opal could not return back, there by changing her (younger Opal) timeline. There would be no "Haven Goblin Rebellion" and all other problems Opal created in that timeline.